# Slickgrid grand totals

Tags: jquery, slickgrid

Is there a way to show grand totals in Slickgrid with grouping?

I found following:

1) In documentation [Implementing a totals row via a data provider](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-totals-via-data-provider.html). But then I can't use DataView and grouping features.

2) There is plugin for SlickGrid called [Slickgrid totals plugin](http://paynen.github.io/slickgrid-totals-plugin/). But it doesn't allow to use grouping features.

Comment: The 2nd one you find seems promising, you should try and build your code with the grouping at first and the attach/register the TotalGrouping after as it seems very easy to attach it.

Comment: Thank you for answer! I am not sure I fully understood you, could you give some code example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Add TotalsDataProvider function

```
function TotalsDataProvider(dataView, columns) {
  var totals = {};
  var totalsMetadata = {
  // Style the totals row differently.
    cssClasses: "totals",
    columns: {}
  };
  // Make the totals not editable.
  for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    totalsMetadata.columns[i] = { editor: null };
  }
  this.getLength = function() {
    return dataView.getLength() + 1;
  }
  this.getItem = function(index) {
    return (index < dataView.getLength()) ? dataView.getItem(index) : totals;
  };

  // Some group-functions from DataView
  this.setRefreshHints = function(hints) {
    return dataView.setRefreshHints(hints);
  };
  this.collapseGroup = function(varArgs) {
    return dataView.collapseGroup(varArgs);
  };
  this.expandGroup = function(varArgs) {
    return dataView.expandGroup(varArgs);
  };

  this.updateTotals = function() {
    var columnIdx = columns.length;
    while (columnIdx--) {
      var column = columns[columnIdx];
      if (!column.hasTotal) { // Just add in your column "hasTotal: true" 
        continue;
      }
      var total = 0;
      var i = dataView.getLength();
      while (i--) {
        total += (dataView.getItem(i)[column.field] || 0);
      }
      totals[column.field] = total;
    }
  };
  this.getItemMetadata = function(index) {
    return (index != dataView.getLength()) ? dataView.getItemMetadata(index) : totalsMetadata;
  };
  this.updateTotals();
}
```

> 2. Add option "hasTotal: true" in your columns. For example:

```
var columns = [
        {id: "id", name: "Index", field: "id", hasTotal: true},
        {id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title"},
        {id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration", hasTotal: true},
        {id: "%", name: "% Complete", field: "percentComplete", hasTotal: true},
        {id: "start", name: "Start", field: "start"},
        {id: "finish", name: "Finish", field: "finish"},
        {id: "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", field: "effortDriven"}
      ];
```

> 3. Change grid variable and add dataProvider variable above:

```
//grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);
var dataProvider = new TotalsDataProvider(dataView, columns);
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataProvider, columns, options);
```

> 4. Every time you change data (by filtering or by grid.onCellCange) you need update total data:

```
// The data has changed - recalculate the totals.
dataProvider.updateTotals(); 
// Rerender the totals row (last row).     
grid.invalidateRow(dataProvider.getLength() - 1);
grid.render();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems like more elegant solution than my. I will test it later.

Answer (score 0):

I found some workaround. The algorithm is as follows:

1. Collect JSON data
2. Calculate grand totals for needed columns
3. Push extra row (array element) at the bottom of JSON data array, with additional param, for example, `noGrouping:true`
4. Push data to `DataView` using`dataView.setItems(JSONDataArray)`
5. In `slick.dataview.js` in function `addTotals`, after line:

   `g.collapsed = groupCollapsed ^ toggledGroups[g.groupingKey];` add:

   ```
   if(g.rows[0].noGrouping) {
     g.collapsed = true;
   }
   ```

   So the group of grand totals is always collapsed
6. If needed, add some formatting in `slick.groupitemmetadataprovider.js` for function `defaultGroupCellFormatter`